# Filter all columns in timeseries to keep only top 1/3

Tags: r, filter, time-series

I have a timeseries with about 100 dates, 50 entities per date (so 5,000 rows) and 50 columns (all are different variables). How can I filter each column in the data frame, per unique date, to keep the top 1/3 of values for each column on each date. Then get the average Return for that group for that date. Thank you.

My data is organized as follows but the numbers in each column are random and vary like they do in column "a" (this is a sample, the real data has many more columns and many more rows):

```
Date      Identity       Return   a     b     c    d     e      f... ...z
2/1/19        X                5      75   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19        Y                4      27   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19        Z                7      88   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/1/19        W               2      55   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/2/19         X               7      69   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/2/19         Y               8      23   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19         X                2      34   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19         Y                3      56   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19         Z                4      62   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19         W               4      43   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/3/19         U                4      26   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/4/19         X                6      67   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/4/19         Y                1      78   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/5/19         X                4      75   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19         X                5      99   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19         Y                 4      72   43     67   85    72     56     92
2/7/19         Z                  4      45   43     67   85    72     56     92
```

I am trying to filter data into quantiles. I have a code that works for filtering into quantiles for one measure. However I want filtered results for many measures individually (i.e. I want a “high” group for a ton of columns).

The code that I have that works for one measure is as follows.

Columns are date, identity, and a a is the indicator I want to sort on

```
High = df[!is.na(df$a),] %>%
    group_by(df.date) %>% 
    filter(a > quantile(a, .666)) %>%
    summarise(high_return = sum(df.return) / length(df.identity)
```

Now I want to loop this for when I have many indicators to sort on individually (I.e. I do not want to sort within one another, I want each sorted separately and the results to be broken out by indicator)

I want the output of the loop to be a new data frame with the following format (where a_Return is the average return of the top 1/3 of the original a's on a given date):

```
Date       a_Return    b_Return    c_Return
2/1/19       6.            7           3
2/3/19       4.            2           5
2/4/19       2.            4           6
```

I have tried the code below without it working:

```
Indicators <- c(“a”, “b”, “c”)

for(i in 1:length(Indicators)){
     High = df %>%
        group_by(df.date) %>% 
        filter(High[[I]] > quantile(High[[i]], .666)) %>%
        summarise(g = sum(df.return) / length(df.identity)}
```

With this attempt I get the error: "Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : Result must have length 20, not 4719.

I also tried:

```
High %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    filter_at(vars(Indicators[i]), any_vars(. > quantile (., .666)))%>%
    summarise(!!Indicators[I] := sum(Return) / n())
```

but with that code I get the error "Strings must match column names. Unknown Columns: NA"

I want High to turn up with a date column and then a column for each a, b, and c.

Comment: Similar but I am looking for a way to do that and apply to all columns in a data frame in a loop or something.

Comment: Yes I am trying to filter data points from each column independently. So I want to end with a new data frame that contains the top 33% of values for each column respectively, for each date.

Comment: So it's won't really be a dataframe, then, right? A "row" won't imply any connection between columns; basically it's just a collection of 50 unconnected vectors. Just making sure I understand correctly

Comment: @divibisan correct, the top 1/3 will differ for each column but the date will be the same. The ultimate output that I want is the average return for that top 1/3 on that date, which would be a data frame I think

Comment: That's much better with the example, though I wish your example data was a subset of your actual data made with `dput` (perhaps `dput(df[1:17, 1:7])`. Also, what are `df.date`, `df.return` and `df.identity`? I assume the first 2 are the real names of the `Date` and `Return` columns in the example data, but what is `df.identity`?

Comment: By the way, thanks for taking the time to improve your question! I know it can be daunting asking your first question here, but taking the time to provide example code and data and to really explain your problem is what makes it possible for us to actually help. So, thanks for an interesting problem! I hope my answer helps

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the identity column. df.identity is the name of each observation. There is only 1 identity for each date.

Comment: Then, does `length(df.identity)` equal the number of rows with the grouped `Date` value?

Comment: Yes it does. I just figured out it also equals the length of return so is redundant

Comment: @divibisan This is extremely helpful! Thank you so much. Two questions to add on... How to have this create a data frame rather than printing the results. And how to go off a list of columns for the one_of() so that I can do this similarly for a < .333 quantile using the same list of columns. Thank you!

Comment: `dplyr` functions return a data.frame, you just need to assign it with `<-`. `one_of` just one of several functions that `dplyr` provides for selecting variables. Take a look at `?select` to see all of them.

Comment: @divibisan and last is there a way to exclude NA’s so that it will still work when columns have NAs. I tried na.rm=True for the sun and length functions but it still had an error for missing values

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` should work for `sum`. Are you sure you used `T` or `TRUE`? R is case sensitive and `True` has no special meaning. `length` doesn't have a problem with `NA` values and will count them as normal (ie `length(c(1, NA))` returns `2`). If you want NA values to not be counted, use `na.omit` inside `length` to remove them.

Comment: Also, since this is your first question, if an answer is helpful you can upvote it and accept it by clicking the green checkmark under the voting arrows.

Comment: How do I assign the function to data frame? I’m having trouble calling it?

Comment: Also, can I return multiple functions within one summarize-at command so that I can get the same results for the lowest 1/3 at the same time?

Comment: `na.omit` is a function so you need to use it like a function : `length(na.omit(data ...`. And yes, as the documentation at `?funs` says, `funs` accepts a "list of functions" which will be run on each column

Comment: I used funs(Return <- sum(Return[. > quantile(., .666)], na.rm = TRUE) / length(Return[. > quantile(., .666)], na.omit))) And am still getting a missing values and nans not allowed if na.rm is FALSE error

Comment: Read about `?na.omit`. It's a function, so you need to call it on your data as you'd do with any other function. `length(na.omit(data ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you combine the filtering and calculations into a single function, then you can put that into `summarize_at` to apply it easily to each column. Since you're example data isn't fully reproducible, I'll use the `iris` dataset. In your case, you'd replace `Species` with `Date`, and `Petal.Width` with `Return`:

```
library(dplyr)
top_iris <- iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(one_of('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length')),
                 funs(return = sum(Petal.Width[. > quantile(., .666)]) / length(Petal.Width[. > quantile(., .666)])))

top_iris

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    Sepal.Length_return Sepal.Width_return Petal.Length_return
  <fct>                    <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>
1 setosa                   0.257              0.262               0.308
2 versicolor               1.44               1.49                1.49 
3 virginica                2.1                2.22                2.09
```

The problem with using `filter` is that each function in the pipe runs in order, so any criteria you give to `filter_*` will have to be applied to the whole data.frame before the result is piped into `summarize_at`. Instead, we just use a single `summarize_at` statement, and filter each column as the summarization function is applied to it.

---

To explain this in more detail, `summarize_at` takes 2 arguments:

The first argument is one or more of the variable selector functions described in `?select_helpers`, enclosed in the `vars` function. Here we use `one_of` which just takes a vector of column names, but we could also use `matches` to select using a regular expession, or `starts_with` to choose based on a prefix, for example.

The second argument is a list of one or more function calls to be run on each selected column, enclosed in the `funs` function. Here we have 1 function call, to which we've given the name `return`.

Like with any tidyverse function, this is evaluated in a local environment constructed from the data piped in. So bare variable names like `Petal.Width` function as `data$Petal.Width`. In `*_at` functions, the `.` represents the variable passed in, so when the `Sepal.Length` column is being summarized:

```
Petal.Width[. > quantile(., .666)]
```

means:

```
data$Petal.Width[data$Sepal.Length > quantile(data$Sepal.Length, .666)]
```

Finally, since the function in `funs` is named (that's the `return =`), then the resulting summary columns have the function's name (`return`) appended to the original column names.

---

If you want to remove missing data before running these calculations, you can use `na.omit` to strip out `NA` values.

To remove all **rows** containing `NA`, just pipe your data through `na.omit` before grouping:

```
iris2 <- iris
iris2[c(143:149), c(1:2)] <- NA

iris2 %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(one_of('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length')),
                 funs(return = sum(Petal.Width[. > quantile(., .666)]) / length(Petal.Width[. > quantile(., .666)])))

  Species    Sepal.Length_return Sepal.Width_return Petal.Length_return
  <fct>                    <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>
1 setosa                   0.257              0.262               0.308
2 versicolor               1.44               1.49                1.49 
3 virginica                2.09               2.19                2.07
```

To strip `NA` values from each **column** as it's being summarized, you need to move `na.omit` inside the summarize function:

```
iris2 %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarize_at(vars(one_of('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length')),
                 funs(return = {
                     var <- na.omit(.)
                     length(Petal.Width[var > quantile(var, .666)])
                 }))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Species    Sepal.Length_return Sepal.Width_return Petal.Length_return
  <fct>                    <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>
1 setosa                   0.257              0.262               0.308
2 versicolor               1.44               1.49                1.49 
3 virginica                2.11               2.2                 2.09
```

Here we use curly braces to extend the function we run in `summarize_at` to multiple expressions. First, we strip out `NA` values, then we calculate the return values. Since this function is in `summarize_at` it gets applied to each variable based on the grouping established by `group_by`.

Comment: I have tried various combinations of na.omit, na.rm, and !is.na in the funs part of the code and have been unable to replicate the original results I had by doing each variable column separately. Is there a way to replicate !is.na for each column as it passes through the function?